# mojo-executor support for plugin dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm using the [mojo-executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) library to call a number of Maven plugins from within another Maven plugin.

However, I can't find any way to specify dependencies on the plugins as I'm invoking them. This is an issue for the `maven-assembly-plugin`, where I need to add an assembly descriptor file as a dependency. Adding the dependency at another level doesn't seem to get the descriptor file onto the plugin's classpath.

Any idea if this is possible, or if mojo-executor could be improved to provide this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to call maven plugins from within a maven plugin? Why not using a usual pom file and define the different plugins in their appropriate lifecycle phase..

Comment: If Maven actually had the support for mixins that was promised a few years ago, I wouldn't have to do this. I am trying to avoid replicating the save few hundred lines of plugin configuration code across five or six different projects. I plan on splitting up the meta-plugin by lifecycle phase.

Comment: Put the plugin configuration etc. into a parent pom which contains a pluginManagement part which solves your problem.

Comment: I don't want to have a parent POM with these configurations, I want something closer to a mixin. Plus, at least in Maven 2, I don't think the pluginManagement behavior is compatible with mixins.

Comment: First if you don't like to have it that way than just implement it and send the patch to the dev list may be it will be accepted. Mixins do not exist in Maven neither in Maven 2 nor in Maven 3.

Comment: I have some thoughts about patching mojo-executor to add this functionality plus support for XML attributes. It seemed odd to me that those features weren't supported already, and I thought I would ask if there was some part of the code I was missing. As it stands, I have workarounds for my particular use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mojo-executor will execute the mojo in an environment without any classpaths. 
You need to manually add the dependency.

```
Dependency dep = new Dependency();  
dep.setGroupId("groupId");
dep.setArtifactId("artifactId");
dep.setVersion("0.0.1-SNAPSHOT");

Plugin assembly = MojoExecutor.plugin(
   "org.apache.maven.plugins", 
   "maven-assembly-plugin", 
   "2.3");

assembly.addDependency(dep)

MojoExecutor.executeMojo(assembly,
   MojoExecutor.goal("single"),
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You know that it's possible to define dependencies for plugins as well:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins.mlv</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-license-verifier-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.licenses</groupId>
        <artifactId>allprojects</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <!-- Optional you can put your configurations here -->
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

This will put the dependency on the classpath of the plugin. That might solve your problem.

Comment: You know that the pre-defined descriptors in the maven-assembly-plugin are working via the classpath? And what does "doesn't work" mean? error messages ? Can you give more details?

Comment: Pre-defined descriptors are working, but the assembly-plugin's classpath apparently doesn't include the dependencies listed on the wrapper plugin. The assembly-plugin says it can't find the named assembly descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to place a requiresDependencyResolution parameter at the @Mojo annotation of our Maven plugin's goal class. Something like this:

```
@Mojo(name = "your-goal", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.xxx,
  requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME
)
public class YourGoalMojo...
```

This is necessary for YOUR Maven plugin to have dependencies resolved and available before/to its execution. The mojo-executor project's README page mentions this just after its maven-dependency-plugin based example:

- https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor/blob/master/README.md

Further information about the @Mojo annotation parameterization can be found here:

- http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html