# How to pass log4j-core to xmlbeans maven generation phase?

Tags: maven-plugin, code-generation, xmlbeans

I found the description of the [xmlbeans 5 maven plugin configuration](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/guide/Maven.html).
It tells to add the dependency on *log4j-core* of the schema generation to the configuration.

However, it seems not to work. I still get the error message

```
SchemaCompiler  Metadata LOAD:org/apache/xmlbeans/metadata GEN:eu/ngong/eaGuid
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

Obviously the *SchemaCompiler* needs *log4j-core* while generating. Is there another way to put *log4j-core* onto the classpath while generating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919753/mojo-executor-support-for-plugin-dependencies?rq=2) helped me.

I had to add the dependency in pom.xml directly in the plugin clause:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <repackage>eu.ngong.tstLog</repackage>
        <name>tstLog</name>
        <noAnn>true</noAnn>
        <partialMethods>ALL,-GET_ARRAY,-XGET_LIST,-XGET_ARRAY</partialMethods>
        <xmlConfigs>${basedir}/src/main/schema/tstLog.xsdconfig</xmlConfigs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```